# How to clean up my if/else LINQ code

Tags: c#, linq

I have something like this:

```
        if (sort == "Customer")
        {
            if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
                myList = myList.OrderByDescending(e => e.SiteOrganization.Organization.Name).ToList();
            else
                myList = myList.OrderBy(e => e.SiteOrganization.Organization.Name).ToList();
        }
        if (sort == "RequestType")
        {
            if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
                myList = myList.OrderByDescending(e => e.TypeId).ToList();
            else
                myList = myList.OrderBy(e => e.TypeId).ToList();
        }
        if (sort == "RequestedByShort")
        {
            if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
                myList = myList.OrderByDescending(e => e.RequestedByUser.ShortName).ToList();
            else
                myList = myList.OrderBy(e => e.RequestedByUser.ShortName).ToList();
        }
```

I would like to clean this up to have something like

```
if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
                myList = myList.OrderByDescending(e => e.RequestedByUser.ShortName).ToList();
            else
                myList = myList.OrderBy(e => e.RequestedByUser.ShortName).ToList();
```

So that I only have ONE LINQ query no matter what "sort" it is. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's ugly like crap and very repetitive

Comment: I'd suggest a switch for the first level and a ternary for the nested level

Comment: @Omid: but it's clear. You could have a look at this dynamic approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: Is `myList` an `IQueryable<T>` or an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @James it's a List<T>

Comment: here's an example: http://pastebin.com/B7tKcT8S which could easily be used with James' SortBy method :) I'd definitely suggest a switch for this though as it's easier to read, and pretty much built for this.

Answer (score 4):

If you move your sort logic into a method, you can pass the predicate straight in e.g.

```
public IList<TSource> SortBy<TSource, TMember>(IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TMember> selector, SortDirection direction)
{
    if (direction == SortDirection.Descending)
        return list.OrderByDescending(selector).ToList();
    else
        return list.OrderBy(selector).ToList();
}
...
if (sort == "Customer") {
    list = SortBy(list, x => x.SiteOrganization.Organization.Name, SortDirection.Descending);
} else if (sort == "RequestType") {
    list = SortBy(list, x => x.TypeId, SortDirection.Ascending);
} else if (sort == "RequestedByShort") {
    list = SortBy(list, x => x.RequestedByUser.ShortName, SortDirection.Descending);
}
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qbk0dY)

---

If you wanted to use this as a general solution to all lists, you could create it as an extension method

```
public static class ListExt
{
    public static IList<TSource> SortBy<TSource, TMember>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TMember> selector, SortDirection direction)
    {
        if (direction == SortDirection.Descending) {
            return list.OrderByDescending(selector).ToList();
        } else {
            return list.OrderBy(selector).ToList();
        }
    }
}
...
list = list.SortBy(x => x.TypeId, SortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: Although I like the `SortBy` method, you've kinda glossed over the original `sort` variable.

Comment: @Rawling I guess the point of the answer was to target the crux of the problem. I can update to accommodate the `sort` parameter as well.

Comment: Not me, but I've just noticed you're only passing one generic argument to a two-generic-argument method.

Comment: +1 for `general solution to all lists`. I was going to post one myself after reading your first half of the answer.

Comment: @Rawling the second generic argument is implied by the predicate so it's not required. In fact, it's all implied therefore I shouldn't need to pass any arguments the more I think about it. Neolisk yeah upon writing the answer I realised that it is generic enough to be re-used, I also think the `SortDirection` enum could be simplified to an `asc` bool (unless the OP has other sorting conditions).